# Metropolis Monte Carlo with modified acceptance

Tags: monte-carlo

What happens, if I change the acceptance criterion in a Metropolis Monte Carlo algorithm?

I do know the classic proof of detailed balance, which for symmetric transition matrices gives a set of states according to the Boltzmann distribution.

Would detailed balance still be fulfilled, if I change the acceptance criterion to e.g. include a third case or use an acceptance function different than the Boltzmann distribution? Would this just result in an unphysical but mathematically valid distribution of states?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [Introduction to the Monte Carlo Method, by Andrea Pelissetto, on pag. 143 (section 6)](http://www.fis.unipr.it/~direnzo/ModSim/pelissetto.pdf), detailed balance is satisfied as long as the acceptance probability for a move is 
\begin{equation}\tag{6.143}
\frac{F(z)}{F(1/z)} = z     
\end{equation}
where
$$
z = \frac{\pi_j p_{ji}}{\pi_ip_{ij}}
$$
and the $\pi$ denote the equilibrium probability of a given state and the $p$ the probability of proposing a given transition.

As long as this condition is satisfied, the Metropolis algorithm will work. Of course, since $F(z)$ is a probability, it has to be less than 1:
$$
F(z) < 1\,.$$

Moreover, since the probability to undergo the reverse transition must also be less than one, we have
$$
F(1/z) < 1
$$
and substituting this equation in the (6.143), we get
$$
F(z) < z\,.
$$
Therefore, it must be
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
F \leq \min(1,z)
\end{equation}
and if you want to maximise the acceptance probability (which you probably do, so that your system evolves as fast as possible), you can set
$$
F(z) = \min(1,z)\,.
$$

This leads us to finally answer your questions:

**Can I choose a different F(z)?** Yes, as long as the condition 1 is satisfied. E.g., $1/(1+z)$ is perfectly valid. However, your system will be moving slower than it should.

**Do I have to use the Gibbs distribution?** No. You can use the metropolis algorithm to sample any distribution you like, however, you are likely to be dealing with systems distributed according to the Gibbs distribution.

**What if I introduce a third option, apart accepting or rejecting the function?** Then it's not the Metropolis algorithm any more, but it's probably something more similar to the heath bath algorithm  [(same file and section as before (section 6))](http://www.fis.unipr.it/~direnzo/ModSim/pelissetto.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, I started to look into it. I'm still a bit confused, how to apply this to my problem, but at least I*m a few steps further than I was.

Comment: If there's a specific problem you want to study with the Monte Carlo algorithm then you could probably post a question either here or in scicomp.stackexchange.com. I or other users might be able to help you :-) some systems, like the Potts model, are not efficiently studied with the Metropolis algorithm: other algorithms (again, like the heath bath algorithm, or the Wolff algorithm) are better suited for some problems.